# Is there a reason to add a directory to the link path twice?

Tags: c++, makefile, ld

I was just given someones `c++` code, a language I am relatively new to.  Looking at the `Makefile`, there seem to be some sloppy and inconsistent uses but perhaps this is just my inexperience.  In this line from the `Makefile`, is there a reason to include `-L$(DIRLIB)` twice?

```
$(CC) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -L$(DIRLIB) -l$(LIB) -L$(DIRLIB) -lboost_regex-mt -o $@
```

I realize the order matters because it determines the search path but I would be surprised if `ld` found anything in the second instance that was not in the first instance.  This seems like a mistake, as the code compiles fine when I remove the second.

Comment: Was the makefile generated using an automated configuration tool?

Comment: Almost 100% certain this is a mistake.  You are sure you've typed the command here correct and that there are upper/lower case differences in the command line or anything?  If it were auto-generated, I could see something like this happening as well.  Then there's the delete it and try it method too :)

Comment: I copied and pasted this from the `Makefile` to prevent errors in typing.  I am certain that is what it has.  I did remove the second instance and the code seems to compile and run fine.  @Barmar, I am not sure if it came from an automated configuration tool but I doubt it.  The `$(DIRLIB)` variable has different values for different systems we use (mac vs linux server) though this could have been edited later.  It is rather short as well, only 30 lines (not sure if that matters).

Comment: Then I can't think of a good reason for it, the original programmer may simply have been confused.

Comment: Would one of you like to write an answer, stating there is no reason to link the path twice, but also include a link to an automated configuration tool which seems to be an acceptable exception?